# Where did she hide the switchblade to cut throat?

Tags: plot-explanation, ted-2

In *Ted 2* there is dialogue between Ted & his wife:

> Wait a minute. 
>   You brought your switchblade?
>
> But they patted us down on the way in here. Where'd you even hide it?
>
> Oh!

So where did she hide the switchblade? oh! means what?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie but the dialogue suggests a private part, such as the buttocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She hid it in her vagina. Oh means that Ted got it.